# Communication between two docker containers(db and simple java application) on same port

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, containers

I am a beginner to the docker. Recently I was trying to connect a simple java application with a Postgresql with docker containers.

I guess my docker for the Postgresql works fine:

Postgresql dockerfile

```
FROM postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_DB testdb 
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Java app dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN javac DBCheck.java
CMD ["java", "-cp", "./postgresql-42.2.8.jar:.", "DBCheck"]
```

This is my directory structure

[image: my working directory]

What is the goal?

The goal is to create two Docker containers: one for the database and another for a java application. The java application should connect to the database from one container to the database container.

I build my PostgreSQL container using following commands:

```
$ docker build -t postgres-db .
$ docker run -d --network="bridge" --name db -p 5555:5432 postgres-db
```

and Java app container

```
$ docker build --tag=java-db-app .
```

when I run my java application with `docker run java-db-app` it returns me an error:

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I am using this url to connect to the database `String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb";`

I have tried also the different commands but the goal was not achieved.

```
$ docker run --name app -p 5555:5432 --link db:db java-db-app
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint app (c944c9542dc8633940a9cae6d8cdf7213cce43be126334c4ffff2648e339fba2): Bind for 0.0.0.0:5555 failed: port is already allocated.
ERRO[0004] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Other commands tried:

```
 docker run -itd --name app -p 5556:5432  java-db-app
 docker run d --name app -p 5556:5432  java-db-app
```

My java code DBCheck.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb";
        String user = "postgres";
        String password = "postgres";

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()")) {

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println("ldahsfs");

            }else{
                System.out.println("Failed next!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems with localhost. So I used docker0 ip address.

```
$ ifconfig
```

you should find a docker0 interface and copy the inet (172.xxx.yyy.v)

Postgres dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_DB testdb 
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Java app dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN javac DBCheck.java
CMD ["java", "-cp", "./postgresql-42.2.8.jar:.", "DBCheck"]
```

DBCheck.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String user = "postgres";
        String password = "postgres";
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://**docker0->ip-address**/testdb?user="+user+"&password="+password;
        try (
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                // Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()")) {

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("\nVersion: "+ rs.getString(1)+"\n");
                System.out.println("Successfully selected the version!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Failed next!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

First, run the database: 
docker build -t database .
docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 database

you should see this message in terminal: `database system is ready to accept connections`

Then, build your application

```
docker build -t java-app .
docker run --name app --link db java-app
```

This is how I was able to work with two docker containers.

Answer (score 1):

So, your local port mapping is wrong in `docker run -d --network="bridge" --name db -p 5555:5432 postgres-db` you have mapped local port 5555 with docker port 5432. While java container tries to run it runs in different network than postgres. 
Hence, either use `docker network connect` command or use ``docker-compose`.

I would recommend using docker compose as that organises your code well and by default connects your images on same network.

I recommend using docker-compose. Sample below:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
 postgres-db:
  image: db:latest
  ports:
   - 5432:5432
 java-db-app:
  image: java-db-app:latest
```

Comment: it gives me the error: ERROR: pull access denied for db, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Comment: You must create your account on docker hub and configure it on local.